# Azure Web App Bot - Access local resources

Tags: azure, bots

My Web App Bot should return images, based on the request. The images are located in the .csproj in a folder, with following configuration

[image]

The sourcecode to send the image to the user

```
        var imgMessage = context.MakeMessage();

        var attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.ContentUrl = $"{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority}/Resources/{InvocationName}/{InvocationNameExtension}.jpg";
        attachment.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        attachment.Name = "Image";

        context.PostAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);
```

While it works locally, it doesn't work after it has been published to the Azure cloud. However, the path to the Azure cloud is something like: h**ttps://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/Resources/img/Cafeteria.jpg**

The FTP upload did include the file

```
2>Adding file (xxxx\bin\Resources\img\Cafeteria.jpg).
```

The file is on the server, but it can't be accessed. How am I supposed to include an image, located in the .csproj? I don't want to refer to an external URL due independency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the Build Action to: "Embedded Resource".

```
        string resourceFile = ResourceManager.FindResource(InvocationName, InvocationNameExtension);
        string resourceFileExtension = ResourceManager.GetResourceExtension(resourceFile);

        var attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.ContentUrl = BuildImageUrl(resourceFile, resourceFileExtension);
        attachment.ContentType = $"image/{resourceFileExtension}";



    private string ConvertToBase64(string resourceFile) => Convert.ToBase64String(ResourceManager.GetBytes(resourceFile));

    private string BuildImageUrl(string resourceFile, string resourceFileExtension) => "data:image/" + resourceFileExtension + ";base64," + ConvertToBase64(resourceFile);
```

With this approach I send directly the content of the image via base64 to the user. Works like a charm